# Override taxonomy term display page with panel page

Tags: 7, views, panels, taxonomy-terms

- I am having a menu built using taxonomy terms which links to a URL pattern like shop/[Term name] this is a dropdown menu.
- I have created a panel page which takes an argument in the URL i.e (shop/!argument).
- In the panel I have added a contextual filtered(has Taxonomy term) view and checked "send arguments" option in settings.
- so obviously the taxonomy term display page is where I land when clicking the links.
- I don't want to use the taxonomy term panel or the views page for taxonomy which comes with drupal core itself.
- I want my panel page to override the taxonomy term display page 
  this is only for two types of vocabulary terms, any ideas how?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this tutorial? http://drupaleasy.com/blogs/ultimike/2010/10/taxonomy-term-pages-steroids-using-panels-views